# Android :getVisibility() error

Tags: android

i have alistview when i click the list view it goes to login screen, when login is successful it comes back to the listview with a icon ..so far its working good, problem is when the icon appear again if i click on the listview the loginscreen is comming ..i dnt want the login screen to load again once the icon is visible..i tried the following but it is giving errors

```
if (img.getVisibility() == 8) { 
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);                  
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @teekib Post your full code.

Comment: my code http://pastebin.com/WukbpTcB

Comment: there is some other error in your activity because your code is working here.

Comment: oh  isit letme try once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not really on your UI state for app logic. You would better use startActivityForResult, then in onActivityResult set a flag and use this flag in your click listener, use it also to make the icon visible or not.

You should also consider setting the flag in the shared preferences for persistence if you leave your activity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result. That's a good start. It allows to create a second activity and get some result back to the first.

Comment: @Snicolas..can u suggest how to set the flag in shared preference..thankyou

Answer (score 4):

use

```
if (img.getVisibility() != View.Visible)
```

Dont use hardcode values.

Answer (score 2):

Change your condition  as:

```
if (img.getVisibility() == View.Visible)
```

**EDIT :** or better way you can use  [View.isShown()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isShown%28%29) for checking View or it's child's are Visible or not

Answer (score 1):

what kind of error you face ?? can you show it to use ? you should not use a hard code value to compare the visibility use one of these  `View.GONE` or `View.INVISIBLE` or `VIEW.VISIBLE`

like this

```
if(img.getVisibility != View.VISIBLE){
// do something 
}
```

Comment: tried the above peice of code..still error..getting nullpointer exception on tht line

Comment: this line return null  img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.redeye);

Comment: where you make setOnClickListener with a Loginplaces class instance

Comment: in an adapter..Loginmyplaces loginmyplaces=new Loginmyplaces(activity);   layer.setOnClickListener(loginmyplaces);

Comment: note that Loginmyplaces class should contains an imageview with id of "redeye" so when you make findViewById it will not return null if the id redeye exist in it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if (img.getVisibility() != View.Visible)
```

instead of

```
if (img.getVisibility() == 8)
```

check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29